# define inline file in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently using a bind mount to mount a file from the host to a container:

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./localstack_setup.sh
    target: /docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh
```

Is there a way to define the `./localstack_setup.sh` inline in the `docker-compose.yml`? I want to use a remote Docker host, and `docker-compose up` fails because the remote host doesn't have the file.

Comment: see discussion at https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/issues/346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [Docker Compose version 2.23.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.23.1), released on Nov 15th, 2023 this is now possible. See the release notes for [Compose Specification 1.20.1](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-go/releases/tag/v1.20.1).

```yaml
name: config-inline
services:
  service:
    image: ubuntu
    entrypoint: cat
    command: /path/to/config.txt
    configs:
      - source: config.txt
        target: /path/to/config.txt
configs:
  config.txt:
    content: |
      strawberry fields forever
```

```bash
$ docker-compose up
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                        docker:default
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Network config-inline_default      Created                            0.0s 
 ✔ Container config-inline-service-1  Created                            0.0s 
Attaching to service-1
service-1  | strawberry fields forever
service-1 exited with code 0
```